# How to reduce the disk size of a VM in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created two VMs having size of 1 TB disk size. Though the VMs are not running , even then I found that GCP was charging me for the disk space. How can I reduce the disk size to lower the cost.What are the other alternatives? There are lot of services installed on this VM and creating new VM from scratch is not an option.

I have explored the followings.

1. Google documentation: Which says, reducing disk size is not a option.
2. Creating VM from snapshot: Apparently , this also does not allow to reduce the disk size.
3. Creating VM from machine image: No luck here as well

Answer (score 0):

You can'd reduce the disk size, but only spin up a new instance from a startup script.

Answer (score -2):

Is [this](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/resize-server-disk/) working for you? the document has detailed steps

- Select the “Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances” menu item.
- Select the instance you wish to resize.
- In the “Boot disk” section, select the boot disk of the instance.
- On the “Disks” detail page, click the “Edit” button.
- Enter a new size (GB) for the disk in the “Size” field.
- Click the “Save” button at the bottom of the page.

and the last step you have to do is to restart the instance.

***UPDATE***

As @Kerem commented: [official doc says:](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd)

> You can only resize a zonal persistent disk to increase its size. You
>   cannot reduce the size of a zonal persistent disk.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd offical doc says `You can only resize a zonal persistent disk to increase its size. You cannot reduce the size of a zonal persistent disk.`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!